# Android - Share Bitmap in Facebook, Twitter, ... Without saving in storage

Tags: android, facebook, bitmap, sharing

How can I share Bitmap in Facebook, Twitter, Mail, ... without saving the image in the internal or external storage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would temporarily write your bitmap to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), and use that to debug your basic share-the-file logic.

Then, implement a `ContentProvider`, where you override `openFile()` and serve up your `byte[]` of PNG (or JPEG or whatever). Then use a `content://` `Uri` pointing at your `ContentProvider` in your `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`, instead of a `Uri` pointing at external storage.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/GrantUriPermissions) demonstrates the basic structure. In my case, I am serving a file from assets, rather than from memory, so you would change that portion of the logic. Also, I am using the `ContentProvider` for an `ACTION_VIEW` request instead of `ACTION_SEND`, so there would need to be changes there.

How well this will work will depend on how quickly the third-party app will read in the contents from your provider and whether you can arrange to hold onto the bitmap in memory that long.